# Cannot find an installable/working stock Themes apk installer after accidentally uninstalling it

Tags: twrp, stock-android, huawei, stock-rom, themes

My device: Huawei Mate 10 Lite

ROM: RNE-L21C432B130.

Recovery: TWRP.

Rooted phone.

I accidentally uninstalled the Themes app (the theme setter, not the theme downloader).
The app was a Huawei's version and was installed as a system app.
I don't have a Huawei account and haven't tried pursuing the "update and get it from Huawei" way. I would prefer this as a last resort solution (IF that is a possible solution).

I have looked everywhere online for a working Theme app's apk installer but to no success. Most versions don't get installed. Some give errors when installed with TWRP, some get installed but crash on launch.
Is there a "universal" Themes app that works fine with most phones?
If no, how or where do I get and install the Huawei's Themes app on my phone?

Comment: If it is a system app you can only uninstall it with root permissions. Otherwise the app gets simply disabled. A disabled app can just be reenabled without having to install anything.

Comment: I uninstalled it with root permissions (using Link2SD), so it's surely uninstalled...